# How to create context menu from the list which contain multi line

Tags: android, contextmenu, listactivity

I have some question, If I create listview like this

[text]

[text]

---

[text]

[text]

---

each list contain 2 lines and I want to make context menu
when I try long press to each list it will show context menu

So how to create context menu from the list which contain multi line....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you registering the ListView for the context menu using

```
registerForContextMenu(listView);
```

or are you creating your own context menu using
`listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(onItemSelctedListener())`?

In both cases, there shouldn't be a problem because they act reacting to each element of the ListView

However, if you are using

```
listView.setOnLongClickListener(onLongClickListener)
```

then you are registering it to the whole list, and it doesn't matter where you press in the list, its going to bring the same context menu.

I hope that helps you with something.